# How to serve file download with resume capability in Play Framework 2?

Tags: file, download, playframework-2.0, resume

How to serve file download with resume capability in Play Framework 2?

I had used this route:

```
GET         /assets/*file           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

and this action:

```
public static Result downloadFile(String filePath) {
    File file = new File("public/files/"+filePath);
    return ok(file);
}
```

But they did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using HTTP byte ranges.  I know this was a question for video streaming, and there's a pull request here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1097

but this is not a part of Play itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Play behind Apache Http server and delegate the downloads to Apache by adding this to the `apache2.conf` file of the Apache Http Server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName <domainname.com>
   #This skips the proxy if the url is <domainname.com>/downloads
   ProxyPass /downloads !
   Alias /downloads /var/www/html/downloads

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

After that add a route in `routes.conf` pointing to the download file

```
/downloadapp     controllers.Application.download()
```

In the download method use something like this:

```
public static Result download() 
{
    return redirect("http://<yourdomain.com>/downloads/file.rar");
}
```

Or simply put the link straight in the html page.

```
<a href=”http://<yourdomain.com>/downloads/file.rar”>Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code (java) from github and it works nice:

https://gist.github.com/felix-schwarz/8385098